# Android Studio: How to attach javadoc

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, android-studio

It might be very trivial question, But I couldn't find any option to attach javadoc/source with local jar dependencies (in libs folder) in android project. I can't believe I have spent a hour on such simple stuff :(

Google search result just tells about adding android documentation or adding javadoc in eclipse. That's not What I am looking for!

Answer (score 39):

I found a solution just now since I can't find any other solution for a long time.

suppose:

1. your lib name is: libxxx.jar
2. javadoc name is docs.zip

under folder .idea/libraries, you can find libxxx.xml. replace JAVADOC with

```
<JAVADOC>
  <root url="jar://C:/yourpath/doc.zip!/" />
</JAVADOC>
```

then ctrl+alt+y to sync the project. (Don't do "Sync Project with Gradle files", it will delete the changes)

Comment: +1 because it works, but not being able to sync with gradle files is far from perfect

Comment: +1 (as per above comment) because it works
-1 because its a hack :)
Google saddens me and it's not a first time

Comment: +1 it worked for me. I exported a .jar file with resources (source code, javadoc) and just added the same snipped for _CLASSES_, _JAVADOC_ and _SOURCES_: `<root url="jar://$PROJECT_DIR$/app/libs/LibraryName.jar!/" />`

Answer (score 38):

I've found & tested a way in which we can add the javadocs without loosing them after a gradle sync.

1. Right click in **Project panel**  > **External libraries** > **lib-name**
2. Click **Library properties**
   [image: Lib props]
3. Click specify documentation URL
4. And specify an URL. For my machine it was `file:///opt/android-sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/docs/reference`
   [image: Add doc url]
5. The result was:
   [image: added jdoc]
6. And after a project sync I could browse the javadoc of the **google play services**
   [image: google play services maps javadoc]

#### Note:

This placed the same JAVADOC entry in the xml identified by [Jason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25438703/209427) but doesn't disappear after doing a sync with gradle

Comment: this is the best answer for the question

Comment: This only works with maven attached libraries though

Comment: @JensV see Robyer 's answer for how to use this with local .jar

Answer (score 17):

It is possible:

1. Open `Project structure`
2. Navigate to dependency that you want
3. Press button from the screenshot and provide folder or file

[image: screenshot 1]

Another way to attach sources:

1. Step into class from library (Hover mouse over class name and do CMD + Left click or CMD + B)
2. You will see decompiled version of class there menu on the top right side of editor "Attach sources.."

[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: That's only going to work until the next time you sync your project. Source attachment isn't implemented in Gradle yet so the changes don't get persisted anywhere that will survive a sync.

Comment: @ScottBarta Yeah, sources are not persisted. Is there any workaround?

Comment: @EugenMartynov When I open project structure and select Android SDK I see a totally different view and have no possibility to "add" anything.

Comment: This answer is invalid in Android Studio 0.4.5

Comment: Sorry, I can not find way how enter dependencies now

Comment: @EvanLeis You can still click use the second method to add sources in Android Studio 0.4.5

Comment: The proposed solution from the editor does not work when attaching javadoc.

Comment: any solution for attaching javadoc folder as of 0.6? its really annoying

Comment: I'm usually attaching sources. All good libraries are shipped in maven with sources. This gives me ability to debug even and read javadoc for method if I want

Comment: Is it really needed to attach sources manually? IDE's dependency manager should know better than user which sources/version is actually used for specific project. So, which javadoc/source should be attached.

Comment: Yeah, I meant that I usually ask IDE to download sources

Answer (score 14):

I had problem with answer from **Matyas** that I wasn't seeing my local .jar library in the *External Libraries* list, because it only show maven attached libs.

Solution is mentioned here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=73087#c26

1. Right click on the "Structure" tab and check "Split Mode" (so you can open both "Project" and "Structure" tabs at same time).
2. Open both "Project" and "Structure" tabs at the same time.
3. In "Project" tab select "Android" perspective and then select your module folder (e.g. "app")
4. In "Structure" window you should now see list of all libraries, including your local *.jar

Continue as in answer from Matyas:

5. Right click on wanted library and select "Library Properties..."
6. If you have *.jar with javadocs locally, you can press "add" button (green "+") and search for the file on your disk (you don't have to type "file://" path manually).

Comment: Verified this solution works in Android Studio 3.0.1

Comment: I found this hint about "Project" + "Structure" tabs at the same time very very useful. And not only for adding javadoc for local library, but also, because "Structure" shows Module Dependencies, and we have project with two dozens of modules.

Comment: I have a zip file with the javadocs for a .jar, but Android Studio 4.1 doesn't show any documentation for any classes/methods. Did something change?

Comment: @DarkNeuron Try extracting the ZIP somewhere and linking to that folder or using JAR file instead of ZIP file for the docs, as I just found this old post: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206824245-Java-8-JRE-javadoc-for-offline (maybe it's not really related, but may be worth try)

Comment: @Robyer Thanks, already tried that; sadly it didn't work. :( Maybe Android Studio is just buggy regarding this use case.

Answer (score 2):

Still a current issue as of my posting it seems:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=73087

Answer (score 1):

After some investigation, I stumbled upon this:

https://github.com/xujiaao/AARLinkSources

Works like magic!

Comment: The linked project is now deprecated as this functionality is built into Android Studio 1.4+.

Answer (score 1):

I wasted so much time on this too...

Here's a gradle task which finds source and javadoc by location/naming convention, and registers them in the .idea files on sync. It belongs in the root gradle file's allProjects section. As-is, it expects to find **[projectname]/libs/lib.jar** next to **lib-sources.jar** and/or **lib-javadoc.jar**. Also, as noted in comments, if your javadocs not pathed at "/" inside the jar, you may need to change the script to add "docs/html" (for example) at the end of **"jar://$doc!/"**.

```
allprojects {

    task addJavaDoc {
        afterEvaluate {
            // Specify paths, this will be run per non-root project
            def projectDir = project.getProjectDir().getCanonicalPath()
            def rootDir = project.getRootDir().getCanonicalPath()
            def lib = projectDir + '/libs'

            // println lib // Uncomment this to troubleshoot
            // Get any jar dependencies register in the lib folder
            fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], exclude: ['*-source.jar', '*-javadoc.jar'], dir: lib ).each { File jar ->
                def jarName = jar.getName()
                def moduleName = jarName.substring(0, jarName.lastIndexOf("."))
                // IntelliJ does this to file names when making the xml files
                def escapedName = moduleName.replace("-", "_").replace(".", "_")
                def xmlFile = "$rootDir/.idea/libraries/${escapedName}.xml"
                // println xmlFile // Uncomment this to troubleshoot
                if (new File(xmlFile).exists()) {
                    ['javadoc', 'sources'].each {String docType ->
                        // Get sources or java doc by naming convention, (expects name-sources or name-javadoc
                        def doc = "$lib/$moduleName-${docType}.jar"
                        // println doc // Uncomment this to troubleshoot
                        if(new File(doc).exists()) {
                            def xml = new XmlParser().parse(xmlFile);
                            def xmlTag = docType.toUpperCase()
                            // Perform xml replacement by convention
                            xml.library[xmlTag].replaceNode {
                                "$xmlTag" {
                                    root(url: "jar://$doc!/")
                                }
                            }
                            // Write out changes
                            new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(xmlFile))).print(xml)
                            // Notify that changes worked
                            println "Fixed up reference to $doc"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, if you are using jcenter or mavencentral, javadocs and sources should work for downloaded jars without using that task, but you may have to add this in each non-root gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'idea'

idea{
    module {
        downloadJavadoc = true
        downloadSources = true
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally tested successfully!

1.Project Structure(ctrl+alt+shift+s)

2.SDK Location

3.JDK Location

4.UnCheck "Use embedded JDK(recommended)"

5.Select your own jdk path(My Path:C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111)

6.Synchronized(ctrl+alt+y)

[success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHzPp.jpg)

Comment: This might enable javadoc for JavaSE (if the JDK comes with javadoc/source) but not for android SDK.

Answer (score -1):

in android studio if you use `compileSdkVersion 23` in buidl.gradle and you have downloaded the SDK 23 document file and source file in `SDK manager` , the android API and java API doc and source will all show auto, **you don't need to manual set.**

Comment: That's only for the android platform, this question is about other libraries.

Answer (score -1):

There is a solution, This procedure take place through terminal ,

I have tested solution in **MAC OS**.

1) Move to your project folder

2) `ls -al` (to show hidden files)

3) Move to `.idea` folder , Command : cd .idea

4) Move to `libraries` folder , Command : cd libraries/

5) Now you can see list of all xml files for your libs or jars. Edit it like , `vi open androidasync_2_1_7.xml`

6) In the editor screen ,
For inserting

```
Press i
```

Now you see `<SOURCES />` tag we have to provide a path here like,

```
<SOURCES>
  <root url="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/androidasync/src/main/java" />
</SOURCES>
```

For exiting

```
Press Esc

    :wq //for exiting and saving
    :q! //for exiting without saving
```

7) Restart Android studio (Sometime it needed also sync gradle).