# adding Parse javadoc to Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, parse-platform, javadoc

Parse provides docs as external `Parse-1.5.1-javadoc` folder.

I would like to have Parse javadoc connected within Android Studio. How do I achieve that?

I'm using AndroidStudio 0.6 and parse 1.5.1.

Same problem:
[Android Studio: How to attach javadoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994336/android-studio-how-to-attach-javadoc)

Android issue tracker:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=59220

Comment: There is a gradle script that can be adapted so that sync doesn't overwrite your changes in [Android Studio: How to attach javadoc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994336/android-studio-how-to-attach-javadoc/43650504#43650504)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the only solution I've found so far:

Open `/YourProjectDir/.idea/libraries/Parse_versionCode.xml"`

Add the following lines:

```
<JAVADOC>
  <root url="https://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/" />
</JAVADOC>
```

So it should look something like this:

```
<component name="libraryTable">
  <library name="Parse-1.8.3">
    <CLASSES>
      <root url="jar://$PROJECT_DIR$/app/libs/Parse-1.8.3.jar!/" /> <!-- check version! -->
    </CLASSES>
    <JAVADOC>
      <root url="https://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/" />
    </JAVADOC>
    <SOURCES />
  </library>
</component>
```

Comment: Actually, that's awesome working solution for now! Thank you!

Comment: @Drew no problem, just keep in mind that when you sync your project this setting is overwritten. kind of annoying but I still don't have a better solution

Comment: Can't find a `.idea` folder in my project. See example structure: https://github.com/firebase/friendlychat/tree/master/android

Comment: That's because it's not committed (you can see it blacklisted in gitignore file). Also it will be hidden on unix machines since it has a dot. You'll still have it once the project is built.