# Android Studio 0.8.2 How to attach javadoc support library

Tags: android, android-studio

I need attach javadoc for support library v4:20 on my project. My libs folder is empty. It's not contains support library. My project is working, however the support library is no javadoc. My build.gradle is:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    // You must install or update the Support Repository through the SDK manager to use this dependency.
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+'
}
```

The library support was added in this way:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Android Studio 1.2.1.1 its still not fixed.

To add javadoc in a jar to a custom library, you should refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/29083067/1378959 , which involves manually adding the jar reference to your `.idea` folder for the library.

This worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately it's not possible at this time, but it's something the devs are looking into. See [this Google Groups post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/adt-dev/yVPo71O_ZKM/BcYP-hLai2wJ).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately we have to wait.