# How to attach javadoc to custom .aar file in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, javadoc, android-library, gradlew

I had created a library project which creates .aar file and also generating javadoc using gradlew command.

Now,I am adding that .aar file in other project and it is working fine but I want to attach created javadoc to that .aar file.

How can such a thing be possible in android studio?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24169763/adding-parse-javadoc-to-android-studio  I found this solution and it works, but after 'Sync' need to add it manually.

Comment: Can anyone tell me a better solution if anyone knows?

Comment: For now it seems the best solution available. It's the only thing I got to work properly.