# How do I generate a .jar file from javadoc generated html?

Tags: java, android-studio, javadoc

I am working on an Android Studio project and I need to export the Javadoc documentation for an AAR package that we are going to distribute.

Apparently Android Studio does not yet support this automatically, so I would like to generate a separate .jar package containing the documentation that can be then imported by Android Studio (or IntelliJ).

I have tried simply making a jar file of the generated documentation folder but importing the resulting jar file as Android Studio module does not enable me to see the documentation of the classes from my AAR package.

Using Eclipse and/or Maven is not an option. I would like to obtain the .jar archive manually only using javadoc and jar tools if possible.

Comment: `jar cf jar-file input-file(s)` ? what about that doesn't work. Was the file not recognized?

Comment: "Without success" -- what happened when you tried it? Also, are you looking to do this manually, via an `ant` task, ...?

Comment: I've added more precision to the question. I do have the jar file but if I import it as a module into the project it does nothing. It might be that my question should be more about "how to import documentation from a .jar file into Android Studio".

Comment: @scrappedcola You are right, the jar file made this way is perfectly usable. My real problem was the way to import the documentation into Android Studio and that I solved by following this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994336/android-studio-how-to-attach-javadoc