# How to add a javadoc JAR-File in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, jar, javadoc

How can I add a javadoc-jar-file to my app project?

I added a core-library to my libs-folder and added it via:
- right click on library
- add to library
- module

Now I have got another JAR, that contains the javadoc for it. Handling it the same way gives me no Javadoc while coding.

How does it work?
Thanks!

Comment: This seems to be the only way currently. https://coderwall.com/p/ybnbbw/attach-javadoc-to-android-studio-project

Comment: The google issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=59220

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994336/android-studio-how-to-attach-javadoc/43360466

Concretely see my answer there: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43360466/2801482