# Android Studio: Importing API with its doc

Tags: java, android, api, javadoc

I'm relatively new to android but learning fast.
One thing that boggled me is, when adding an API, let's say the Youtube API to android studio, is how to also add its documentation to be available when clicking CTRL+Q.

I downloaded the compressed folder which contains a JAR for the API, and a folder for documentation which includes an "index.html" among others.

I copied the JAR to the libs and it worked correctly and I tested the sample apps.
But there is no documentation on any class/method/etc...
I tried to copy the "doc" folder itself to the libs folder, I tried to zip it and convert it to a JAR file in the libs then add it as a dependency, Synced with Gradle, Rebuild project, but no change.

What am I missing? What is the correct way to implement the documentation in Android Studio of downloaded APIs?

Thanks for the help. I've wasted too many hours searching online...

---

EDIT:

This is a screenshot of the project structure with the API added as a dependency to the "app" module.
The docs are not in that JAR file, but google provided them seperately as HTML, which i have compressed into a JAR file. (not sure if this step is useful)

[image]

This is how the doc jar looks like inside:

[image: doc JAR]

I'm expecting it to work when I CTRL+Q on any class from the youtube API, so far nothing worked.

Comment: I did a google search and came up with this Stack Overflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30372625/how-to-add-a-javadoc-jar-file-in-android-studio it seems there might be an issue around this, as the solution looks pretty manual

Comment: You're right, this is what I came up with also but I thought after 2 years the issue would have been resolved. 
I added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who found this post, the solution is manual AND has to be done after each gradle sync, check this [link](https://coderwall.com/p/ybnbbw/attach-javadoc-to-android-studio-project)
(except i disagree on the fact that it's only web-based javadoc, it worked local for me with html-based javadoc not jar, condition is to have it end with /reference/ as in c:/javadoc/docs/reference/ otherwise android studio won't find the javadoc)

It's not a perfect method, not all info will be shown but better than nothing.