# How to view JavaDoc of library in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

We have an Android library project that we use in a couple Android app projects. When developing the Android app in Android Studio, if I hover over classes or methods defined in the library, the documentation popup has the package and signature, but no JavaDoc content.

The library is not in the same project as the application. It is built separately and uploaded to a private artifact repository (I think it's Nexus) and then referenced as a gradle dependency.

How do I get Android Studio to show the library's JavaDoc comments when viewing the class or method from the app project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [AARLinkSources](https://github.com/xujiaao/AARLinkSources) plugin may be able to solve this for you. I haven't used it myself, but it is [recommended by a Stackoverflow user as an answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29617618/1214974).

Comment: Not quite what I was hoping for but still the best option available, I guess.