# Adding .jar with javadoc to android studio

Tags: java, android

I have two files: `library.jar` and `library-javadoc.jar`. How can I import the library into my project in Android studio, such that Android Studio will show me the Javadoc when I mouse over something from the library? To be clear, the problem isn't getting the library into my project because I've already done that. I am struggling to find a way to attach the javadoc. I've been tearing my hair out and I've googled the answer a million times but I can't find anything. I don't understand why this has to be so hard, it was dead easy in eclipse.

Comment: There is a gradle script that attaches sources/javadoc in [Android Studio: How to attach javadoc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994336/android-studio-how-to-attach-javadoc/43650504#43650504)